# C++, Convert 1D Array into 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to convert code that is currently using two functions to create a character 2D Array into one function that creates a character 2D Array.

The contents of the Array is the alphabet from 'A' to 'Y' (omitting 'Z', as I need a matrix of 5*5 size). Notes: I cannot use vectors or pointers.

The below code works, but it needs to be converted into one function, which I am having considerable trouble doing. I have been researching but I cannot find a clear enough solution, and I am a beginner in C++.

```
// Fills 4-Square Matrix 1 with Alphabet (1D Array)
void fill4Square1(char* FourSquare_1_Matrix)
{
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < 25; n++)
        FourSquare_1_Matrix[n] = 'A' + n;
}
// Fills 4-Square Matrix 1 with Alphabet (2D Array)
void fill4Square1_1()
{
    char FourSquare_1_Matrix[5][5];
    fill4Square1((char*)FourSquare_1_Matrix); //Function Call for 1D Array
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) //For Loop puts 1D array into 2D Array
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            cout << FourSquare_1_Matrix[row][col] << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

I wrote the below code, but I cannot get the contents of the 1D Array into the 2D array. The 2D Array is being filled with random char characters. [Program OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnmol.png)

```
void PlayFairMatrix1()
{
    int i = 0;
    char Matrix[25] = { {0} };
    char PlayFairMatrix[5][5] = { {0} };
    int n;

    //1D Matrix
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        Matrix[i] = 'A' + i;
        cout << Matrix[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";   
    cout << " " << endl;

    ////2D Matrix
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            PlayFairMatrix[row][col] = Matrix[i];
                i++;
        }
        cout << PlayFairMatrix << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << " " << endl;

}
```

Can anyone please help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies on this line `PlayFairMatrix[row][col] = Matrix[i];`

`i` starts off with the value 25 from previous loop. And you never reset it back to 0.

So, the simplest way to fix it is just add `i = 0;` before the second loop.

Another way will accessing `Matrix` using row and col, but I will leave that for you as an exercise.

Also, when you print `PlayFairMatrix`, you are not accessing it with index so you will print the pointer instead. You should put `cout << PlayFairMatrix << " ";` into inner loop and add the index, so it becomes `cout << PlayFairMatrix[row][col] << " ";`

Comment: I tried resetting `i` back to zero `i = 0` at the beginning of the 2nd loop and before the 3rd loop, and the output does not seem to be affected.

Comment: Yes, and the code is working now -  Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

While populating PlayFairMatrix, you forgot to reinitialize variable `i = 0`. That will fix your code.

But you can do it simply as follows

```
void PlayFairMatrix1()
{
    char PlayFairMatrix[5][5] = { {0} };
    int i = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < 5; ++row)
    {
       for(int col = 0; col < 5: ++col)
       {
           PlayFairMatrix[row][col]='A'+i;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. After resetting `i = 0;` and moving  `<< cout << PlayFairMatrix[row][col] << " "; ` into the inner loop, the code works.